# What is flat Cartan-Eilenberg resolution?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, homological-algebra, sheaf-theory

In the proof of SGA 4, XVII, Proposition 4.2.10, the author makes a "flat Cartan-Eilenberg resolution" of a complex of sheaves.

> Soit $K$ un complexe vérifiant (a). ... Soit $K_1^*$ une résolution plate de Cartan-Eilenberg et posons $K_2 = \tau_{\ge -N}^{\prime\prime} K_1$ (troncature dans le sens de la nouvelle différentielle). La flèche composée de $K_2$ dans $K$ est un quasi-isomorphisme, ...

But I only find the definition of projective and injective Cartan-Eilenberg resolutions. So what is flat Cartan-Eilenberg resolution?

Comment: I don't have an ounce of knowledge in homology so I'll leave this as a comment unless you find my proposal good enough, but reading about this in your source and in *Cartan-Eilenberg complexes and resolutions*, Edgar E. Enochs, 2011, it would seem to me that a flat Cartan-Eilenberg resolution is merely a Cartan-Eilenberg resolution on flat complexes (and then flat complexes and flat resolutions are defined for example on Wikipedia). What makes me think that is the text after "Scholie 4.1.3" of your source and how projective/injective C-E resolutions are defined by Enochs, but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I found a possible way to work it out (I don't know whether it's correct). For $K^\bullet$ bounded above, just take a flat resolution of $K^\bullet$. For $K^\bullet$ unbounded, we have $N < \infty$. There is a complex of flat sheaves $P_0^\bullet$, which is split exact, with a surjection $\varepsilon: P_0^\bullet \to K^\bullet$. So we have a quasi-isomorphism $K^\bullet \cong (\ker\varepsilon)^\bullet[1]$. Inductively, we can construct a complex (of complexes)

$$\cdots \xrightarrow{d_{n+1}} P_n^\bullet \xrightarrow{d_{n}} \cdots \to P_1^\bullet \xrightarrow{d_1} P_0^\bullet \xrightarrow{d_0=\varepsilon} K^\bullet \to 0 \to \cdots$$

which is exact and satisfies $(\ker d_n)^\bullet[n+1] \xrightarrow{\mathrm{qis}} K^\bullet$. The double complex given by $P_{\bullet}^\bullet$ satisfies our requirement.